# android: convert LaTeX code into a View

Tags: android, latex

does anyone know, how i can compile and display LaTeX code in my app? I already had a look at JLaTeXMath-android, but apart from having troubles builing it, i'm looking for something that wouldn't force me to provide my source code along with the product, e.g. something that is not licenced with GNU GPL(i think GNU LGPL would be ok).